# AWS S3: Remove same file in many folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, bucket

I have this situation on my AWS S3 bucket

```
My bucket
├───Product 1
│       sales_Product 1_1.pdf
│       sales_Product 1_2.pdf
│       prod1.pdf
│       prod2.pdf
│
├───Product 2
│       sales_Product 2_1.pdf
│       sales_Product 2_2.pdf
│       prod1.pdf
│       prod2.pdf
│
└───Product 3
        sales_Product 3_1.pdf
        sales_Product 3_2.pdf
        prod1.pdf
        prod2.pdf
```

My question is: How to delete prod1.pdf and prod2.pdf using recursive option?

I tried to use `aws s3 rm s3://My bucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "prod1.pdf" --include "prod2.pdf"` but does not working

Comment: If you want to match a partial key, you need to include a wildcard: `aws s3 rm --dryrun s3://example-bucket/ --recursive --exclude="*" --include="*/prod1.pdf" --include="*/prod2.pdf"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `*` in the object name as they can be in any tree:

`aws s3 rm s3://$Bucket --recursive --exclude '*' --include '*/prod1.pdf' --include '*/prod2.pdf'`

```
> aws s3 rm s3://mknappe-tmp --recursive --exclude '*' --include "*/prod1.pdf" --include "*/prod2.pdf"
delete: s3://mknappe-tmp/a/prod1.pdf
delete: s3://mknappe-tmp/b/prod2.pdf
delete: s3://mknappe-tmp/c/prod1.pdf
delete: s3://mknappe-tmp/a/prod2.pdf
delete: s3://mknappe-tmp/c/prod2.pdf
delete: s3://mknappe-tmp/b/prod1.pdf
> aws s3 ls s3://mknappe-tmp/a/
2022-10-27 09:16:25      11623 prod3.pdf
```

Comment: My awscli version for windows will ignore everything inside single quotes, so `aws s3 rm s3://$Bucket --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*/prod1.pdf" --include "*/prod2.pdf"` will work, while using single quotes like in the answer gets me everything deleted in the bucket.. Always use --dryrun to test the command first.